# Google Analytics custom variables

Tags: google-analytics

I have a question regarding tracking a single user by username in Google Anayltics, if can answer it?

There are two sides to our website, the public site and a log in site that allows our clients to log in to their account to collect any documentation we may have provided to their organization. We do not ask them to enter any personal information other than their company email address and job title; these accounts are only for our client as an organization.  Anything that is within the portal is all documentation that my company has provided to them. There can be multiple usernames associated with one account.

We are in need of a tracking which users within an origination are logging in. So if Jane Doe from Origination A logs in but John Doe never has, we would be able to see that user name in GA. I know Google Analytics offers this kind of tracking using custom variables, but I am concerned it goes against their privacy policy even though we are not tracking personally identifiable information.

So what we are looking to do is track usernames and the page they visit on our site, can this be done using custom variables, and does it violate GA privacy policy? Is the code used placed in your current tracking code?

Can anyone offer in insight?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are collecting usernames which may or may not contain Personal Identifying Information, you are directly violating [Google Analytics Terms of Service](http://www.google.com/analytics/terms/us.html).

Comment: Thanks Blexy. Do you happen to know of any software that does allow you to track user log ins and habits?

Comment: Does it matter if we already have all of their personal information, i.e., email, name, etc.? The purpose of our tracking is only to see if they are using the service.

Comment: If you have access to, say, a backend user id that you could reference as the value of the custom variable, and as long as the user id is numeric and doesn't contain any PII, then you could use that.